# How to sort array of strings by length in reverse/descending order in Swift?

Tags: swift, sorting

I would like to order a collection of strings in descending order, according to length.

Firstly, I'm not sure if I should be using a set or an array, given that a set is a collection of unordered things and I don't need the elements in the collection to be necessarily in an ordered collection.

I came across the `sorted()` method and the `sorted(by:)` method but can't work out how to do the descending order by length - just by alphabetical order.

```
let strings: Set = ["andy", "ber", "ed", "gerald"]
let descendingStrings = strings.sorted(by: >)
print(descendingStrings)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sorted()` takes a closure to do the comparison (the `>` operator is a closure, since all methods are closures). So:

```
let descendingStrings = strings.sorted { $0.count > $1.count }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to order a collection of strings in descending order, according to length, then you can write:

```
let descendingStrings = strings.sorted { (a, b) -> Bool in
    return a.count > b.count
}
```

And if you want the longest string first and sort the rest ascendingly, then

```
let descendingStrings = strings.sorted { (a, b) -> Bool in
    if a.count == b.count {
        return a < b
    } else {
        return a.count > b.count
    }
}
```

Change the  `<` and `>` signs according to your needs. Hope this will help.

Comment: This works great too, thanks a lot for your answer. A question, since I haven't come across closures yet, how can we just give two arguments a and b, when we have a collection of more than two things to compare to one another? Is this iterative?

Comment: To say simply, it works as a function that takes two parameters and returns a bool value. And yes, iteratively.